# Do a make-up exam have the same questions/exercises as the original exam?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the definition given by a [site](http://arts.uwaterloo.ca/~jredekop/MakeupFAQ.html):

> The purpose of any
>   makeup exam is to allow students, with legitimate reasons for missing
>   a scheduled exam, to fulfil the requirements of a course, and hence
>   avoid being penalized for factors beyond their control.

I wonder though, if the content of the make-up exam is the same as the original one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question about the English language.

Comment: I think if you [edit] your question to explain why you were unable to find a definition for "make-up exam" that answered your question, we should be able to take it off hold. It seems like folks thought you were asking about a specific site's policy instead of a more general question about the meaning of the term "make-up exam". The page you linked goes on to say "to write a makeup exam **comparable to the final exam written by the rest of the class**, but at a more convenient time", and it's not clear why that didn't help you understand the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of make-up offered by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/makeup) is somewhat broader:

> something that makes up for a previous postponement, omission, failure, or deficiency

If somebody had to take a make-up exam because they failed the original, as suggested by the above definition, it would not be a realistic test if the content of the make-up exam were exactly the same as the original exam.

Comment: +1 Note that how a particular institution defines it may vary. OP’s link suggests their policy is to make it different, as it states the makeup exam will be “comparable”.